# Add condition and joins to connected tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have a user table and it has userRole. I want to add condition that fetch all the users having "role_id" 1 that is in userRole.

Relationship in user Model:

```
public function userRole() 
{   
  return $this->hasOne(UserRole::class); 
}
```

And controller code:

```
$users = User::with(["userRole" => function ($query){
                        $query->where('role_id', 1);   
                    }])->get();
```

This is not working fine. Its fetching all the users and fetching userRole in case if its role_id is 2 otherwise userRole is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. Please try adding the below snippet in your controller

```
User::with(['userRole'])->wherehas('userRole', function ($query) {$query->where('role_id','1');})->get();
```

Comment: You forgot to add "with('userRole')" the correct one is 
User::with(['userRole'])->wherehas('userRole', function ($query) {$query->where('role_id','1');})->get();
Thanks it helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading reverse of relation.
Something like this:

```php
// in UserRole.php file
public function users() 
{   
  return $this->hasMany(User::class); 
}
```

and your query like so:

```php
$role = UserRole::with("users")->where('id', 2)->get();
$users = $role->users;
```

Comment: But this is not feasible for me as I have to add other joins with users also.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution we can do this by wherehas

```
User::with(['userRole'])->wherehas('userRole', function ($query) {$query->where('role_id','1');})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation :**

`with()` is used to eager load. So basically using `with('userRole')` will get you all roles for that particular user.

When you use :

```
User::with(["userRole" => function ($query){
     return $query->where('role_id', 1);   
}])->get();
```

You are telling Laravel, give me all users, and their roles but roles fetched should only have `role_id` of `1`. Do not select roles other than this condition.

Laravel has a function `whereHas` which does not select anything but filters the parent relationship based on on condition of the child.

For example. we need to get users having role id of 1 :

```
User::wherehas('userRole', function ($q) {
    return $q->where('role_id','1');
})->get();
```

Now this will tell Laravel to get me all users who have atleast 1 entry userRoles with role_id of `1`.

This will just filter Users based on relation of roles. However, we need to separately add `with()` clause to get the roles.

```
User::with('userRole')->wherehas('userRole', function ($q) {
    return $q->where('role_id','1');
})->get();
```